# Logback: Prevent appender inheritance? Or: find non-routed logger?

Tags: java, logging, logback

I'm completely new to Logback and I can't really find an answer to a basic conceptual question:

What I'm trying to accomplish is either:

- Prevent appender inheritance, i.e., prevent a certain logger to use the root logger for instance. Kind of like a veto to use a certain appender.
- Generate a kind of "fall back" logger, which will be used if (and *only* if) no logger element matches the basic selection rule.

The motivation for this is that in my use case I do not want a huge global log file. Instead I have split logging into small units / log files. My problem is: I sometimes make mistakes in my logger-split-logic with the result that some messages do not show up in my logs (e.g., a logger obtained from `LoggerFactory.getLogger("non-existent-logger")`). I can obviously set up an appender for the root logger but since this appender is inherited to all loggers the resulting log file will be huge and it is difficult to track down loggers which have not been routed according to my split rules. So my question is how to deal with this problem in Logback?

Comment: Look at the [`SiftingAppender`](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/access/sift/SiftingAppender.html) - you can split the output into different log files depending on some criteria.

Comment: I'm already using a `SiftingAppender` in some cases to [generate log files dependent on the logger name](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18398028/1804173). However I see the same fundamental problem: Applying the appender at the root level still results in unwanted logging since I don't want to inherit this appender to certain specific loggers...

Comment: Just revisiting the questing and somehow I must have missed that it is a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21597827/1804173). The answer given there literally does _prevent appender inheritance_, so voting to close...